# create external table in hive as a select query pointing to s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I am attempting to create a table in Hive environment and point it to an external location in S3. 
When I try :
create table x (key int, value string) location 's3/...' 
it works well.
But, when I attempt :
'create external table as select x,y,z from alphabet location 's3/...'
it doesn't run. Is there a way to create a table as a select statement and store it at an external location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a managed table using the select statement and update the table property to External.

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')
```

or

Write the output of the select query to a location

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY ‘/myDirectory’ 
  SELECT * FROM PARAGRAPH;

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name> LOCATION '/myDirectory'
```

Comment: With the first option, how would one specify the external location? Though second option can serve the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Using the first option, it creates an external table pointing to default hive location(hive/warehouse/<DB>/<table>). It still be an external table as the data and metedata are decoupled. If you drop the table, data will not be deleted.